# FFMPEG intermittent failures reading live RTMP stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp, live-streaming

### The Command

I'm attempting to read a live RTMP stream and save the result to a file with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -rtmp_live live -y -i "rtmp://<server>/<app>/<stream>" -c copy -f flv /tmp/dump.flv
```

I run this command then after 10-15 seconds I kill the process and check `/tmp/dump.flv`. I'm trying to do this for stream diagnostic purposes (determine the encoding, bitrate, resolution, pixel format, and key frame interval of the live stream)

This command works about 25-50% of the time. When it works FFMPEG takes about 5 seconds to connect to the stream, then it begins dumping data to disk. After I kill the process, I can find a couple of megabytes of video data in `/tmp/dump.flv` which can be probed using `ffprobe`.

When the command fails, it goes into one of two failure states:

### Failure State 1

stderr is flooded with a series of messages about "missing picture in access unit with size X", and the output file `/tmp/dump.flv` is created but contains 0 bytes

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[NULL @ 0x55b72d568920] pps_id 381 out of range
[AVBSFContext @ 0x55b72d5692c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2200
[AVBSFContext @ 0x55b72d5692c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2 times
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 3171
[AVBSFContext @ 0x55b72d5692c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] no frame!
[NULL @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 80572
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 1560
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2608
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2734
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2885
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 77739
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] non-existing PPS 254 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 3360
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2804
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 3051
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 3067
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 77693
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2421
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2779
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2442
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2678
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 76877
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] sps_id 15 out of range
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 1342
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2412
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 2238
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 3550
[h264 @ 0x55b72d568920] missing picture in access unit with size 3075
...
(after hitting Ctrl+C:)
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://<server>/<app>/<stream>':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 5285.919000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 2543 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 48 tbc
Output #0, flv, to '/tmp/dump.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 2543 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

### Failure State 2

The message "No start code is found." is displayed and FFMPEG immediately terminates after less than a half-second. When this happens the file `/tmp/dump.flv` is not created.

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.4-1~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[NULL @ 0x56274b0be920] missing picture in access unit with size 3710
[AVBSFContext @ 0x56274b0bf2c0] No start code is found.
rtmp://<server>/<app>/<stream>: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://<server>/<app>/<stream>':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 2543 kb/s, 24 fps, 1k tbn
Output #0, flv, to '/tmp/dump.flv':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

### What I've tried

- Adding or removing `-re` to try and limit the input frame rate to the source frame rate
- Adding or removing `-rtmp_live live`
- Adding or removing `-timeout 5` (or any other timeout value)
- Using RTMP URL parameters (e.g. `-i "rtmp://<server>/<app>/<stream> live=1 timeout=5"`)

Does anyone know why this command's success is so intermittent or how I can get more consistent results?

### Alternate Acceptable Solution

The only reason I'm using `ffmpeg` to dump the stream to a temporary file at all is because I plan to perform multiple tests on the file (at least two at the moment -- one to get the encoding, and another to get the key frame interval). By downloading the stream I reduce bandwidth usage and reduce runtime. However it's perfectly acceptable to forego `ffmpeg` and just use `ffprobe` directly on the RTMP URL if this would help.

Note that I did try this and I get the same two failure states with `ffprobe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting these errors when using Red5 v5.0.1 for my RTMP server. Updating to Red5 v5.2.0 fixed the issues. It was just a bug in their server. No idea what was wrong, but it's better now.